# App for fitness videos requiring merging, trimming, changing audio and speed adjusting in Instagram videos for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, video, instagram

I want to create sport training videos like [here](http://instagram.com/p/sxs8NBrLQn/) that requires trimming, merging and audio changing. It would also be extremely useful to change the speed in videos. How can I do them?

Answer (score 1):

Working in progress, community effort.

**Clipper** due to its fast speed and **Videoshop** due its customisation capabilities are recommended for recreational fitness videos like the video in the question. Please notice that Clipper loses your edits and can only edit one production at a time!

**Full-scale almost-desktop-feeling with all kind of bells-and-whistles**

1. [iMovie](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/imovie/id377298193?mt=8&ls=1) (loading, big product...meant for Movie/Hollywood level stuff, overkill -- so much unnecessary adjusting!)
2. [Videoshop](https://appsto.re/us/pfmSK.i) (speed adjusting for each clip, audio for the whole production, possible to work with many productions at a time, unstable and slow to use)

**Improvisation producs that make uploading super fast**

3. [Clipper](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/clipper-instant-video-editor/id649030063?mt=8) (missing speed adjusting, only possible to work on one production at a time -- and clears up memory so you lose your production after a while, bad)
4. [Replay](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/replay-video-editor-for-instagram/id694164275?mt=8) (speed adjusting over the whole production, imposible to specify, example [here](https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=859444627440514))

Comment: Free free to edit if you find faster to me, community answer...

Comment: Hi, this is for Apple products, not Android.

Comment: we don't do android stuff, right?

Comment: added more. I couldn't find a counterpart

Comment: @awesomebing1 awesome work! I removed the android, nevermind, forget :) I tested the apps (iMovie still loading). I think Clipper is the fastest by which you can do this but iMovie/Videoshop has more control to tune specific locations while the improvisation products are mostly automated. The bad side with Clipper is that it allows only one production and you lose all of your edits after a while...